# If yield return never occurs, is null returned?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, yield-return

The method returns IEnumerable via a yield return statement.

If the yield statement never occurs (it's inside conditional logic), will the method return null, or will it return an Enumerable with a count of 0?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A valid IEnumerable that produces no values when you iterate through it.

Just think of it: You can store the IEnumerable generator in a variable - the code itself just gets executed when you actually iterate through the results. How could you execute the code if you had `null`? Or how did you *know* the function doesn't yield anything without running it.

Answer (score 10):

The latter -- you're going to be able to `GetEnumerator()` no matter what, there just won't be any items to enumerate. This is equivalent to `Enumerable.Empty<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, 2.0 coders who leant toward heavy use of enumerations would have a standard piece in their toolkits of:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> EmptyEnum<T>()
{
    yield break;
}
```

Before System.Linq.Enumerable.Empty() came along . Very useful in a lot of cases, quite often precisely because it doesn't return null. For example, if GetIntEnum() can return some sort of IEnumerable type but can also return null, then `GetIntEnum() ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>()` gives us something that is always safe to enumerate over (assuming that's the desired behviour in the case of null results).