# C# Method (Yield) Return Path not detected

Tags: c#, visual-studio, yield

Please consider the very small method below -:

```
IEnumerable<ObjectTest> CreateObjectList()
{
    bool aTest = false;
    ObjectTest anObject = null;
    if (aTest == true)
    {
        foreach (var item in aTestList)
        {
            yield return anObject;
        }
    }
}
```

I feel that this code should not compile. There are paths that do not return as the boolean test fails. The compiler should report-:

> Not all code paths return a value.

But this isn't the case - can someone please explain?

(.NET 4.0)

Richard

Comment: If the `yield return` is never hit, an Iterator returning no elements is returned. Thus a method that `yield returns` may never return `null`.

Comment: If it makes you feel better, imagine that in the last row there is an implicit `yield break;`

Comment: HimBromBeere massive thanks for the fast reply - can you elaborate why and where in the C# spec this is?

Comment: 10.14.4.1: When the end of the iterator body is encountered: The state of the enumerator object is changed to *after*. The MoveNext method returns false to its caller, indicating that the iteration is complete.

Comment: I think this makes for very badly read code. Or is it I am just not fully understanding yield>?

Comment: @RichardHill The second one :-) You must first comprehend the working of yield, then everything becomes clear. The code that you write is transformed very much by the compiler. The "real" code is totally different. So what you are observing is a natural side-effect of how the code is written (and of the 10.14.4.1)

Comment: @Richard - your function defines the return type as an IEnumerable<ObjectTest>.  That means your function needs to either return that, or have a yield break at the end.

Comment: See also [using iterators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/65zzykke.aspx) and [yield](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/9k7k7cf0.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for all who helped on this - I've got a much better understanding of yield - not perfect yet - but its 'happening' - this was one part of a bigger bug that was iterating over a collection in a linq ALL predicate and returning TRUE on an empty list. Its resolved now - but only with all of your input. I want to re-iterate how impressed I was with the speed and content of response - brilliant :)

Comment: Don't forget to mark answer which helped you the most as accepted ;)

Answer (score 3):

As `yield return` wil return an iterator in any case it is guaranteed to never return `null`. Thus a method that `yields` has allways a return-value, namely the iterator. Whether the iterator returns any elements or not is not relevant here.

Maybe [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/16/iterator-blocks-part-three-why-no-yield-in-finally.aspx) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427140/if-yield-return-never-occurs-is-null-returned) may also be interesting.

Comment: Ok - I get this. It shows I don't fully understand the yield and to be extra vigilant when working with it as it obfuscates code in my opinion.

Comment: Would be a perfect answer if you linked to the MSDN with the bit saying that it always has a return value ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just because you're using `yield return` doesn't mean that it covers all paths through your code that are outside of the scope of the `yield return`.

Expanding on what HimBromBeere said in the comments, please consider this:

```
IEnumerable<ObjectTest> CreateObjectList()
{
    bool aTest = false;
    ObjectTest anObject = null;
    List<ObjectTest> objects = new List<ObjectTest>();
    if (aTest == true)
    {
        foreach (var item in aTestList)
        {
            objects.Add(anObject);
        }

        return objects;
    }
}
```

That is basically what you're doing, only allowing for processing "from within" the `foreach` part of you code. That above code will throw the same error.

As was said in the comments, the part that you're missing is that when your `if (aTest == true)` is not valid, the rest of your code doesn't return anything. You can maintain the code that you have above, but just include the following:

```
if (aTest == true)
{
    ...
}

yield break;
```

Comment: Wouldnt it be better if the `yield return null` is `yield break`? Because right it is returning value null after its finished instead of just end the literation

Comment: Brilliant - thanks a lot for the answers everyone really appreciate your time and effort on this.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I was double checking this and figured it out as you made your comment @manuchao . Doing `yield break` as my edit has is the correct way.

Comment: @juharr Yes, I know. That's why I made that example in there, and then stated that he would get the same error. I was doing it to show an equivalent set of code without the `yield return` since that seemed to be confusing the OP.

Comment: But the OP is not getting an error.  The question is "Why don't I get an error?".

Answer (score 0):

Think about what would happen if aTestList would be empty in the following case:

```
IEnumerable<ObjectTest> CreateObjectList()
{
    foreach (var item in aTestList)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Do you understand what will happen? The enumerator won't yield anything. That's exactly what happens in the code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that what you write in C# is not necessarily what is exactly compiled. The `yield` keyword is one of those "syntactic sugar" things that do not result in exactly what you have written.

Try to open the compiled code with a .Net decompiler (JustCode or dotPeek for instance), and check out the IL (Intermediary Language) result. You will see that what is compiled is not what you might expect.

In short, `yield return` is just a shortcut for "create a variable, fill it, then return it".

You can see a bit more explanation here : http://www.dotnetperls.com/yield