# Extension method without a return path

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I wrote an extension method and realized something about it - It has a case of no return path. Given the extension method below, it breaks up an `IEnumerable` collection into smaller collections. So if I give it a collection with 429 elements and pass in a chunk size of 100. Then I would get a collection of collections sizes: 100, 100, 100, 100, 29.

Now, what if I passed in an empty collection. The while loop would never be entered as Any() would not return true. While debugging, I found the returned object was an empty `IEnumerable` collection. Why is this? Why is it not null? Why is no compiler errors thrown for a method with a possible no return path?

Here is the method in question:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Chunk<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int chunksize)
{
    while (source.Any())
    {
        yield return source.Take(chunksize);
        source = source.Skip(chunksize);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427140/if-yield-return-never-occurs-is-null-returned

Comment: The `yield` keyword triggers compiler-based code generation of a state machine. It handles this for you - the methods best default return value can be reasoned to be an empty collection, `null` makes less sense.

Comment: no return at the end of the method works as `yield break`

Comment: _"Why is no compiler errors thrown for a method with a possible no return path?"_ - because a `yield` statement in a method returing `IEnumerable<T>` bends the "old" C# rules. Relevant C# spec term is "iterator block", relevant sentence: _"execution can be interrupted in four ways: By a yield return statement, by a yield break statement, by encountering the end of the iterator block, and by an exception [...]"_

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth how is the "best reasoned" return an empty collection? The default value of IEnumberable is null.

Comment: @Justin because an iteration that yields nothing is empty, also when you consider the general case I would suspect a developer would rather return empty than null, which would break calling code, when implementing a method with yield. I was saying how I would see it, but as with anything in the compiler only the compiler team can say anything definitively.